# I am trying to install storybook in my project using npm storybook init. However, it shows the following error

Tags: reactjs, npm, storybook

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'has-flag'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\6fe9a9991b157df1\node_modules\supports-color\index.js
- C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\6fe9a9991b157df1\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js
- C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\6fe9a9991b157df1\node_modules@storybook\cli\dist\cjs\generate.js
- C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\6fe9a9991b157df1\node_modules@storybook\cli\bin\index.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\6fe9a9991b157df1\node_modules\supports-color\index.js:4:17)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\6fe9a9991b157df1\node_modules\supports-color\index.js',
  'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\6fe9a9991b157df1\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js',
  'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\6fe9a9991b157df1\node_modules\@storybook\cli\dist\cjs\generate.js',
  'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\6fe9a9991b157df1\node_modules\@storybook\cli\bin\index.js'
  ]
  }

Comment: did you already try installing the has-flag module? if not, do a npm i has-flag and retry

Comment: Please use code tag to highlighted all error.

Comment: i tried installing has-flag module

Comment: still not working